Unable to Delete Registry Keys Corresponding to Clean Flash Player
Although I have already uninstalled Clean Flash Player, I am unable to delete several corresponding registry keys and subkeys, that I need to delete for a specific purpose.
I have already tried all conventional methods, including taking ownership/granting privileges, attempting to delete the keys in safe mode, and even using psexec. However none of these methods have worked and the same message was displayed, Cannot delete [NAME_OF_KEY]: Error while deleting key.—which is extremely generic and not at all helpful.
I genuinely have no idea what is going on here. Did Clean Flash Player somehow embed itself as a persistent system driver without telling me? Some instructions for how I can figure out what exactly is preventing these keys from deleted might also go a long way.
ㅤ
These are the registry keys I am attempting to delete:
HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}
HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID{D27CDB70-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}
HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID{B019E3BF-E7E5-453C-A2E4-D2C18CA0866F}
HKCR\WOW6432Node\Interface{299817DA-1FAC-4CE2-8F48-A108237013BD}
HKCR\TypeLib{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}
HKCR\TypeLib{FAB3E735-69C7-453B-A446-B6823C6DF1C9}

If you've tried reading the post, I mention that I have tried both of those things and even more. However, I also need to update by saying that I have solved this issue, only that the solution that worked was to resort to using a premium 3rd party software that could monitor an installation like Clean Flash, and then undo everything that the software logged it doing.

You should change your comment into an answer.
